# Bloch's wavefuction of solid state phyiscs

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

The Bloch's wavefunction is written in the form:
$$\psi_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i\mathbf{k⋅r}}u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$$
where **k** is the lattice momentum and $u_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r})$ is some periodic function. We call **k** the lattice momentum and sometimes the wavevector. Its values $\pm\pi/a$, where $a$ is the lattice constant, define the boundaries of the first Brillouin zone (BZ) in the k-space.

My question is: **Why do we write the subscript "**k**" in the wavefunction above**?

To clarify more. Take the E-k diagram that represents the energy bands of a solid in the k-space. We can draw this diagram in a reduced manner and project all other bands in outer B. zones onto the 1. BZ. Now due to periodicity, each k value (say for 1d now) on the k-axis corresponds to a unique k-value in the 1. BZ. In other words, *each k corresponds to many many energy levels that exist in different bands in the solid*. **What additional information is obtained then by writing this subscript k under Bloch's wavefunction?**

Comment: It tells you something about the behavior under lattice transformations...

Comment: It is not just $u_k$, it is $u_{n,k}$. There are many Bloch wavefunctions, and for any specific band number $n$, the wavefunction will have different periodic functions when $k$ changes. That is, $e^{-i\vec k\cdot\vec r}\psi_{n,\vec k}(\vec r)=u_{n,\vec k}(\vec r)$ will be different functions for different $\vec k$